# Ionic 2 video ad plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, admob

I`m trying to find some good plugin for Ad showing ( videos ) for ionic2. I've tried with https://github.com/cranberrygame/cordova-plugin-ad-adcolony but I can't adjust it to work with ionic2 and angular2. I've also reviewed AdMob , which is ionic2 plugin , but video ads are not supported , as I read (only banners) . Can you please advise me what should I use and how , for my ionic2 app. Thanks.

By the way , when I'm trying to run adcolony this way  `window.plugins.adcolony.showIntersitialAd()` with the HTML below

```
<button ion-button (click)="window.plugins.adcolony.showInterstitialAd();">showInterstitialAd</button>
```

it returns

`HomePage.html:15 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined`

and when I'm trying to run it like this

```
<button ion-button (click)="window.adcolony.showInterstitialAd();">showInterstitialAd</button>
```

it returns the following error:

```
HomePage.html:15 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'adcolony' of undefined
```

any help will be appreciated , thanks :)

By the way , I`m testing the app through https://apps.ionic.io/apps

Answer (score 1):

Try with this plugin: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

Notice that you have to wait for interstitial to be loaded and also is a good idea to disable interstitial loading when your app is in background, as there is a delay between the moment you request an interstitial and the moment you show it:

```
<button ion-button (click)="tryToShowInterstitial();">showInterstitialAd</button>
```

And in your javascript code:

```
var isAppForeground = true;
var isInterstitialAvailable = false;

function tryToShowInterstitial() {
    if (isInterstitialAvailable) {
        admob.showInterstitialAd();
    } else {
        // Do your button action here when there are no ads to show
    }
}

function onAdLoaded(e) {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      isInterstitialAvailable = true;
    }
  }
}

function onAdClosed(e) {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      // Would you like to prepare next interstitial?
      setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
      isInterstitialAvailable = false;
    }
  }
}

function onPause() {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    admob.destroyBannerView();
    isAppForeground = false;
  }
}

function onResume() {
  if (!isAppForeground) {
    setTimeout(admob.createBannerView, 1);
    setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
    isAppForeground = true;
  }
}

// optional, in case respond to events
function registerAdEvents() {
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, onAdClosed);

  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

function initAds() {
  if (admob) {
    var adPublisherIds = {
      ios : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
      },
      android : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
      }
    };

    var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;

    admob.setOptions({
      publisherId:          admobid.banner,
      interstitialAdId:     admobid.interstitial,
      autoShowInterstitial: false
    });

    registerAdEvents();

  } else {
    alert('AdMobAds plugin not ready');
  }
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
  initAds();

  // display a banner at startup
  admob.createBannerView();

  // request an interstitial
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Hi David , thanks for you answer. Ive already integrated AdMob in my project , I am using rewardvideo , but the problem is that , sometimes the reward video ad fails to load :( Sometimes work perfectly , but sometimes fails to load , do you have any suggestion why this may happen ? :(